# PHP regex to replace SQL Query

Tags: php, regex

I have an strange situation where i receive in a function by parameter an XML where a field in particular is a SQL Query. The problem i detected is that i want to modify the sql query on the fly to add some extra things:

What i receive for example is:

```
    <p n="KeyFields"><![CDATA[]]></p><p n="Funciones"><![CDATA[]]></p></q><q i="" t="RequestQuery"><p n="TipoQuery"><![CDATA[ExecuteSQL]]></p><p n="TipoEntidad"><![CDATA[]]></p><p n="Datos"><![CDATA[INSERT INTO ps_module_group 
SELECT 
  m.id_module, 1 AS id_shop, g.id_group 
FROM ps_module m 
  JOIN ps_group g 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( 
  SELECT 1 FROM ps_module_group 
  WHERE id_module=m.id_module AND id_group=g.id_group 
  ) 
]]></p><p n="KeyFields"><![CDATA[]]></p><p n="Funciones"><![CDATA[]]></p></q></qq>
```

The idea is to modify the query with this extra:

```
AND m.id_module != 122
```

So it looks like this:

```
    <p n="KeyFields"><![CDATA[]]></p><p n="Funciones"><![CDATA[]]></p></q><q i="" t="RequestQuery"><p n="TipoQuery"><![CDATA[ExecuteSQL]]></p><p n="TipoEntidad"><![CDATA[]]></p><p n="Datos"><![CDATA[INSERT INTO ps_module_group 
SELECT 
  m.id_module, 1 AS id_shop, g.id_group 
FROM ps_module m 
  JOIN ps_group g 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( 
  SELECT 1 FROM ps_module_group 
  WHERE id_module=m.id_module AND id_group=g.id_group 
  ) AND m.id_module != 122
]]></p><p n="KeyFields"><![CDATA[]]></p><p n="Funciones"><![CDATA[]]></p></q></qq>
```

I'm 100% sure that is not good to do this in the server side but query is generated outside my control...
My problem is that i need to validate the whole query in the regex as other queries could be passed and don't need to be modified, just this exact query. My biggest problem and this is why i'm not able to do it is because of the multiline query that i'm not sure how to enter that in a regex, even more due to tabs, spaces, etc.
I'm using PHP in the server side.

Is there any option?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if I understand it right you receive a XML serialized string as input. Would SimpleXML do the trick to "extract" the sql query? http://php.net/manual/fr/book.simplexml.php

Comment: How do you decide which queries need the extra code added to them? Do you add it to all queries in `<p n="datos">`?

Comment: the way you ask the question, it sounds like you want to modify the XML *before* parsing out the SQL, but that seems a little odd;  eventually, something that is going to use the SQL parses the XML, so that thing should be the thing that modifies the SQL apart from / outside of the XML

Comment: ... if your question is really just about multiline regex in PHP, and the XML and SQL are sort of beside the point, then check out PHP's regex modifiers, particularly `m` and `s` : http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: If it is "this exact query" and it doesn't change, explode the string based on the query and join it on the query with the extra where clause you want.

Comment: I wouldn't be executing no Queries supplied in XML if it comes from userland, I don't know enough about the details of what you are doing to say that, But I wouldn't trust any external source with my database.  Just saying.

Comment: @Ggg extract the query is not the problem, the problem is to modify it as not always the income text  is a query that need to be modified, only the query i posted is the one that needs to be modified.

Comment: @Barmar only this query is the one that needs the extra code, always that this exact query is received would require it, the rest no.

Comment: @Jonathan yes i know how to add the extra to the end of the query, the problem is to detect that the query passed is the one that needs to be modified, only this exact one as you said needs the modification.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix queries come from a trusted source and in this situation this is not the problem.

Comment: That's why I said this `I don't know enough about the details of what you are doing to say that`  Just wanted to make sure you understood the risks, someone had to say it ... lol ... Even still it may be better to have an API, like a search API, it gives a layer of separation between dependencies.  For example if one day you decide to switch to NoSQL like MongoDB, your stuck if you use SQL, if you have an API the end user doesn't care what DB you use, if that makes sense.

Comment: Just recently (at work) I converted a web search form we have on our site, to allow a simple REST like API that can return JSON or XML data, just for example.  It's more work to build an API but it's actually more flexible and robust in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just need to modify this one query, you don't need a regular expression, just use `str_replace()`

```
$query = 'SELECT 
  m.id_module, 1 AS id_shop, g.id_group 
FROM ps_module m 
  JOIN ps_group g 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( 
  SELECT 1 FROM ps_module_group 
  WHERE id_module=m.id_module AND id_group=g.id_group 
  )';
$xml = str_replace($query, $query . ' AND m.id_module != 122', $xml);
```